# Decoding HTML in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

`@` in asp.net mvc 3 preview 1 automaticly encodes html, is there an alternative way to let there be html?

think of this scenario:

`@view.BestSitesEver.Replace("stackoverflow", "<h1>StackOverflow</h1>")`

That would just print out: `<h1>stackoverflow</h1>`

Comment: What would this "stackoverflow" parameter be? A div?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use this

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(site.Replace("stackoverflow", "<h1>stackoverflow</h1>"))
```

This will output the html string *without* encoding

```
@(new HtmlString(site.Replace("stackoverflow", "<h1>stackoverflow</h1>")))
```

And with Erik Porter's comment

Comment: As of MVC 3 you don't need to use MvcHtmlString anymore.  @(new HtmlString("<h1>StackOverflow</h1>")) will work just fine.  Any implementation of IHtmlString will work though.  We're considering a helper or shortcut that would create the new HtmlString for you in the future.

Answer (score 14):

A little bit late now but there's a convenient extension method in MVC3:
Html.Raw():

```
@Html.Raw(site.Replace("stackoverflow", "<h1>stackoverflow</h1>"))
```

Comment: Is there any way of getting this to work within a declarative helper (ie - in App_Code)?  Looks like all Html helpers are broken in there.